# change css through jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have this code in CSS:

```
input.checkmark[type=checkbox] + label:before {
    content:"\f096";
    transform: scale(2);
    color:white;
}
```

I then used it as such in HTML:

```
<div class="checkmark">
   <input class="checkmark" id="box1" type="checkbox" />
   <label for="box1" style="color:white">&nbsp;&nbsp;test test test 
     <span style="font-weight:bold !important; font-size:18px" class="thisChild">
     </span>
   </label>
</div>
```

I would like to change the color through jQuery but nothing seems to work. I have tried this:

```
$("#box1").css("color", "gray");
```

How do I go about this?

Answer (score 0):

You are doing right, but as such there is no color property for `input:checkbox`

Don't forget to wrap your code in DOM Ready

```
$(function(){

    $("#box1").css({"margin-left":"100px"});

});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5Lubc858/7/)